# Transactional job in Kettle Community Edition

Tags: transactions, pentaho, jobs, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

**Using**: Pentaho Data Integration 5.4 Community Edition.

In [documentation](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Database+transactions+in+jobs+and+transformations) there is a statement that gives clarification about database transactions on a job level:

> **Transactions in jobs**
>
> Starting from version 5.0 of PDI (Enterprise Edition) you can also
> enable the same functionality that exists for a transformation in a
> job.  The **"Make the job database transactional"** option is located in
> the "Settings" tab of the job settings dialog.

This is however only available for PDI **Enterprise Edition**. I'm in need for this feature in Community Edition.

I've been trying to do this inside transformations by using `Transformation Executors`, `Mapping transformations` with no success so far.

For a small process I've ended up using `Blocking step` inside a transformation and making the transformation **database transactional**.

Thinking bigger, as of ETL processes for data marts, data warehouses etc where in case of a **failure** full rollback of all processess is needed, how can one go around the issue of not having this feature in CE?

*Edit:* Some of you may have stumbled upon this issue and I'm wondering what would be a different way to approach this problem (excluding full database backup & restore - this will take forever with large databases like data warehouses).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried out version 6.0?  From the "What's New" page:

> **Revert changes in job database transactions**
>
> Database connections can be used with all jobs. This enables commits
>   and rollbacks on a job level. Prior to this release, this was only
>   possible with transformations.

I'm not sure, however, whether that functionality is available in CE.

Failing that, you could use the low-budget approach:  At the beginning of the job, trigger a database backup.  On a failure, restore the backup.

Comment: This is unfortunately only available for Enterprise Edition of Kettle.